# Why does this JSON response have code for an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, json

If you browse certain ISO pages such as [this one](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:pub:PUB400002:en) and look at the network communication as you mouse over items, the JSON response always starts with `for(;;);` before following with actual JSON markup.

Other than perhaps attempting to punish someone using `eval()` to parse the JSON, is there a good reason for this? For example, is it a best practice for guarding against a certain attack vector?

Comment: Have you read [Why is there a for(;;); preamble in facebooks JSON responses?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1804387/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling I have not! Mark away as a dup while I go read that. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, maybe it doesn't fully answer your question :)