# What is the purpose of infinite empty for cycle in responses of JSONP requests?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

What is the purpose of adding "for (;;);" to the response for JSONP requests?
E.g. a response like this:

for (;;);{a:...} (where {a:...} - a JSON string)

What is the difference between passing just {a:...} (if there is any).

Comment: It locks up people who suck down jsonp data with bad/brain-dead handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the answer [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/856084/1350193).

I'll summarize it: The infinite loop restricts access to the JSON data to your own domain. You can load the script on your own site via `XMLHttpRequest` and remove the loop before using/executing the data/script. The loop prevents cross-domain requests though as these would have to use a `<script>` node and thus the loop would be executed.

Note that this doesn't work if someone loads the JSON data/script on a server which can remove the loop and then send the data to the client.